# Define a discounted sale price Prestashop

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop, product, prestashop-1.5

I have a very big problem, I need some products do not specify the discount to be applied to the product or the difference in amount, but to directly specify the selling price including tax, I'll explain:

Sales price without discount -> 30.00

Sales price I wanted -> 12:56

12:56 I want to write directly without having to do subtractions and / or calculations of percentages, can you tell me how can I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the corresponding code in your template file?

Comment: I don't have code... :(